# FtpWebRequest ListDirectory does not return hidden files

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, file-handling, ftpwebrequest

Using `FtpWebRequest` to list the contents of a directory; however, it's not showing the hidden files.

How do I get it to show the hidden files?

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftp_root + path);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
```

FileZilla lists the hidden files correctly so I know the FTP server is returning that data to it. I just need to replicate that with `FtpWebRequest`. Or use a different library for it.

Comment: Does `ListDirectoryDetails` do what you want?  MSDN documentation on it is very sparse.

Comment: Show us verbose FileZilla log file. And try the `ListDirectoryDetails`, as Brendan suggested.

Comment: ListDirectoryDetails also did not return the hidden files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FtpWebRequest` which is provided by Microsoft does not perform all the operations neccessary for listing FTP, FTPS or SFTP site's directories.

A good solution would be to use some other dll's like WinScp, Ftp.dll which can provide you with some efficient and extra functionalities.

Comment: I ended up using FluentFTP https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentFTP which has an option to list hidden files like so: client.GetListing(path, FtpListOption.AllFiles);

Answer (score 3):

Some FTP servers fail to include hidden files to responses to `LIST` and `NLST` commands (which are behind the `ListDirectoryDetails` and `ListDirectory`).

One solution is to use `MLSD` command, to which FTP servers do return hidden files. The `MLSD` command is anyway the only right way to talk to an FTP server, as its response format is standardized (what is not the case with `LIST`).

But .NET framework/`FtpWebRequest` does not support the `MLSD` command.

For that you would have to use a different 3rd party FTP library.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) you can use:

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "ftp.example.com",
    UserName = "user",
    Password = "mypassword",
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    RemoteDirectoryInfo directory = session.ListDirectory("/remote/path");

    foreach (RemoteFileInfo fileInfo in directory.Files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0} with size {1}, permissions {2} and last modification at {3}",
            fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length, fileInfo.FilePermissions,
            fileInfo.LastWriteTime);
    }
}
```

See documentation for [`Session.ListDirectory` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_listdirectory).

WinSCP will use `MLSD`, if the server supports it. If not, it will try to use `-a` trick (described below).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

If you are stuck with `FtpWebRequest`, you can try to use `-a` switch with the `LIST`/`NLST` command. While that's not any standard switch (there are no switches in FTP), many FTP servers do recognize it. And it makes them return hidden files.

To trick `FtpWebRequest` to add the `-a` switch to `LIST`/`NLST` command, add it to the URL:

```
WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/ -a");
```